# iOS - how to change button image without resizing and repositioning the button view

Tags: ios, ios7, uibutton, uiimage

I currently have a view containing 2 buttons - The view size is 320px wide and 52px tall.
Each button is 160px wide and 52px tall, and they stand one next to each other covering the whole view. Each button has a 160X52 image associated to them. The following behavior is happening:

- when rendering the view I can see a padding rendering of the two buttons - I gave the background view a white color and can see a white line around each button. How can I have this removed?
- second and most important - when clicking on one button I am having the image replaced with another one 160px wide but 62px tall. When rendering the view i see the Image resized instead of overflowing outside of the view. When checking the bounds and center properties of the button however, they have not changed.

I am not a view designer expert and I definitely have to do a lot more reading on how the rendering engine works, but if anybody can drop a couple of hints of what to look at to get me started it would be very helpful.

Tanks a lot

Comment: post your code on how you setting images to button

Answer (score 0):

That's the code for a butto;

```
    UIButton *firstButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50.0, 50.0, 160.0, 52.0)];
[firstButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backGroundview"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:firstButton];
```

And that's 2 images of how the buttton looks when pressed. Are you sure you don't have any autolayout rules or a different image for the button? Instead of using "setBackgroundImage" you use setImage it will resize the button to the image size.

[image: Not pressed]

[image: Pressed]